# Is switch performance over enum cases O(1)

Tags: swift, performance, enums

I couldn't come across information regarding performance of a switch statement over all enum cases. Say you have 100 cases. Is it O(1)?

```
enum MyEnum {
    case one = 1
    case two = 2
}

let myEnum = MyEnum.one
switch myEnum {
    case .one: ...
    case .two: ...
}
```

Comment: I just did a quick test with 1024 cases vs 8 cases, both switching over each case and constructing a case from a rawValue. Both yielded performance of 0.000s. So, it looks like it, though I should probably increase that test size to 1,000,000 cases.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the assembly code (“Debug” » “Debug Workflow” » “Always Show Dissembly”) for the `switch` statement, one can see that it is O(1) (at least in this simple case, at least). For example, here is the `switch` code:

[image]

Don’t get lost in that code, but note that it’s very few instructions that set the contents of `rdx` to be the address of the code associated with that particular `case`:

[image]

The details here aren’t really relevant, but the key is that in my enumeration with 1,000 cases, it didn’t run through 1,000 tests but rather it calculated the address by calculating from index in this enumeration, and just jumped to the relevant code.

---

All of this having been said, enumerations usually don’t generally have enough cases that the complexity of the `switch` statement would ever be observable. And if you did have thousands (or millions) of different cases, there would be so many other problems with the code, that the complexity of the switch statement would be the last of your concerns, even if it weren’t O(1).

Comment: Brilliant! From what I would guess, anything that is hashable should be O(1). "All" you have to do is build a hash table. Not sure if I should mark this answer as definitive? Looks to me like the compiler verifies that is. Let me hold off for a bit. Maybe some new information will come to light. Thank you!

Comment: As long as you mean “hashable” with the lowercase “h”. But this isn’t a `Hashable` thing. Make your enumeration non-hashable by adding some associated values and you still basically enjoy O(1) behavior (except of course if you start adding pattern matching or `where` clauses in your `switch` statement, and even then, the hit is limited to those cases, still largely O(1)).

Comment: I do mean lowercase "h", but actually an enum case can be set to `AnyHashable`, so it is a `Hashable`? And yes, if you add associated values this changes things, but in this case you no longer really have `rawValue`. Interesting though that you still get O(1). Perhaps there still is some lowercase "h" hashing going on under the hood.

Comment: The performance may have nothing to do with hashes. It looks more like it’s just using the index of enumeration to achieve O(1) performance